# use i18n-2 in node.js outside of res scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, internationalization, global

Im trying to aim so i can use i18n within functions that is called.

I have the error:

```
(node:15696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: i18n.__ is not a function
```

How can i make so i18n would work inside functions and dont have to be within a req?

Server.js:

```
var    i18n = require('i18n-2');

global.i18n = i18n;
i18n.expressBind(app, {
    // setup some locales - other locales default to en silently
    locales: ['en', 'no'],
    // change the cookie name from 'lang' to 'locale'
    cookieName: 'locale'
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.i18n.setLocaleFromCookie();
    next();
});

//CALL another file with some something here.
```

otherfile.js:

```
somefunction() {
               message = i18n.__("no_user_to_select") + "???";

}
```

How should i solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read the docs carefull under [Using with Express.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-2#using-with-expressjs), it's clearly documented how it's used. After you bind `i18n` to express app through `i18n.expressBind`, `i18n` is available through the `req` object available to all express middlewares like:

```
req.i18n.__("My Site Title")
```

So `somefunction` should either be a middleware like:

```
function somefunction(req, res, next) {
  // notice how its invoked through the req object
  const message = req.i18n.__("no_user_to_select") + "???";
  // outputs -> no_user_to_select???
}
```

Or you need to explicitly pass in the `req` object through a middleware like:

```
function somefunction(req) {
  const message = req.i18n.__("no_user_to_select") + "???";
  // outputs -> no_user_to_select???
}

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  somefunction(req);
});
```

If you want to use `i18n` directly you need to `instantiate` it as documented like

```
const I18n = require('i18n-2');

// make an instance with options
var i18n = new I18n({
    // setup some locales - other locales default to the first locale
    locales: ['en', 'de']
});

// set it to global as in your question
// but many advise not to use global
global.i18n = i18n;

// use anywhere
somefunction() {
  const message = i18n.__("no_user_to_select") + "???";
  // outputs -> no_user_to_select???
}
```

Many discourage use of global.

```
// international.js
// you can also export and import
const I18n = require('i18n-2');

// make an instance with options
var i18n = new I18n({
    // setup some locales - other locales default to the first locale
    locales: ['en', 'de']
});

module.exports = i18n;

// import wherever necessary
const { i18n } = require('./international');
```

Comment: For my current functions that I need to call is called within each other with a possibility of not having any req object. Possible to get languages based on userid that have some sort of i18n variable saved? I get what you mean here. (Y)

Comment: Then you can use the global version by making an instance first. `Possible to get languages based on userid that have some sort of i18n variable saved` assuming you're retrieving from some db?

Comment: Yes saved in db. Will chrck answer

Comment: How would i approach this If some variable is based on userid database? I know this is out of the original question.   Thanks for approach, will accept.

Comment: you can use `setLocale(locale)` given `locale` is defined in your `option` like `.setLocale('de')` (assuming you've retrieved `de` from db)

Comment: How Can i pass userid param to send to the international.js?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191760/discussion-between-naga-elixir-jar-and-maria).